# Certain line in email message grabbing software

Tags: email, webgrabber

Is there a way to grab the email messages from outlook.com and store them in a txt or csv file as text? Is there a software/freeware that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

MSN/Outlook.com offers no API that let´s you achieve this. If you really need to extract email addresses from incoming emails on your msn account you will need to use Imap to get the messages and parse them through php or .NET or likewise.
I really see no other way.

You might want to [read more here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) for php examples.

Comment: I was reffering to email message content. Wondering if, maybe, there is a data extractor for Microsoft Outlook out there. Any tips?

Comment: To the best of my knowlege there are no such native plugin or application except the solution suggested in my answer. Sorry.